# Python match elements of jth row of list with other rows

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a list of lists where I want to compare all elements of a specific column to find matches. More specifically say I have the following table:

```
Item_No.      features
   A        ['X','Y','Z']
   B          ['X','Y']
   C            ['Y']
   D            ['S']
```

I would like to see if Item A has any common feature with other items. In this case, I want to obtain something like this:

```
Item_No.    features      Common
   A      ['X','Y','Z']    B,C
   B        ['X','Y']       A,C
   C          ['Y']         A,B
   D          ['S']         0
```

How would I proceed with this on python?

Comment: Did you tried something by yourself first ?

Comment: Why do B,C have nothing in *common*? You should correct the example or specify *common*. **OT:** The tags added to the question look a bit far fetched.

Comment: @nitzel - Edited.

Comment: As Kedar Kodgire already said, if you show us what you have tried, we are willing to help you out. From [another post of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553887/python-webscraping-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-modal-window-content) I know that you know about `for in` and `in`. That's a good start for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def common(x,y):
    """Do list x and y have an element in common?"""
    for e in x:
        if e in y:
            return True
    return False

#listnames and their content
data = [('A',['X','Y','Z']),
        ('B',['X','Y']),
        ('C',['Y']),
        ('D',['S'])]

# touples of listnames and an array of listnames it 
data_common = [] overlaps with
# try common on each pair of lists saving their names.
for N,A in d:
    data_common.append((N,[n for n,a in data if(n is not N and common(A,a))]))
print(data_common)
```

Output: `[('A', ['B', 'C']), ('B', ['A', 'C']), ('C', ['A', 'B']), ('D', [])]`

This is quite expensive, about `O(m^2*n^2)`, `m=max(len(data[,1])), n=len(data)`
and could, of course, be optimised since each list is actually checked against
each other twice.

Comment: Sorry I was a little busy after I posted my question and was not able to post my work code. Thanks a ton @nitzel.